# Debian 7 how are IPv6 link local addresses set?

Tags: ipv6, linux-networking, dhclient

It seems like when dhclient runs on eth0 I get an IPv4 address from the DHCP server and a Scope:Link IPv6 address attached to eth0:

```
inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fed0:4d41/64 Scope:Link
```

But I can't see from dhclient-script how that address is being added.  On another interface with a static IP address, I'd like to add a link local IPv6 address, and I was wondering if there was a generic command to do that without knowing the mac.

Edit:
It looks like the kernel assigns the link local address when you do "ip link set dev ethX up" or "ifconfig ethX up".  However, in my case I had a cable plugged in to the interface that was DHCP'ing and no cable plugged into the interface I was setting up statically.  Can't verify until Monday but I'm guessing the kernel does not assign link local addresses to the interface if there's no link.

Comment: Neither has anything to do with the other.

Comment: I understand that.  And yet, as a result of running dhclient you get an IPv6LL address, but when you set a static IPv4 address you don't.  So some side effect of some command being run by dhclient sets that up..

Comment: No, you do not get an IPv6 link-local address from running dhclient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Link local addresses are derived from the MAC address of the device.  They are auto-generated as a part of bringing the interface up.  Auto-configuration includes a discovery process to ensure that the address is unique on the network.

A similar process is used to auto-configure routable addresses when a router advertisement is available.  These addresses may be regenerated periodically to provide privacy.

[RFC 4862](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862) specifies the processes to be followed.

Comment: "They are auto-generated as part of bringing the interface up".  Right, this is what I'm looking for, who is autogenerating it?  It's not auto-generated when you assign a static IPv4 address, but it is when dhclient runs.  So is dhclient implementing RFC 4862, or is it a side effect of some command in the dhclient-script?  How do I replicate it on a static interface without writing my own implementation of RFC 4862?

Comment: auto-generated by the kernel, it seems, see edit above.

Answer (score 6):

Found it! This command is not enough:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Instead I must do:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6=0
```

Only the latter does restore the IPv6 link local address on eth0.

In other words, my distro seems to have some code hidden somewhere which dynamically changes `net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6` every time it is asked to bring the network brought up or down. Your mileage may vary.

I got to the bottom of this thanks to a mere:

```
sysctl -a | grep ipv6
```

Comment: By the way I can't understand why my distro is flipping disable_ipv6: once the link is brought down it does make any difference.

Comment: This applies perfectly to Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.